# Need help in integrating libvlc with drm encrypted media content [.mlv file]

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I have a player which plays drm encoded mlv file but the Audio and Video is not in sync on medium configuration windows machines. Trying to find some open source libraries and came across libvlc. I am able to write a wrapper around libvlc but need help in integrating libvlc with drm encrypted media content [.mlv file]. The content has to be played offline.

Comment: Can you show what you already have?

Comment: Is it possible to libvlc wrapper to talk to drm sdk?